# Ensure unique identifier in List<CustomObject>

Tags: c#, uniqueidentifier

I'm creating an Excel add-in that will allow a user to generate [PURLs](http://purls.source4.com/index2.htm) by specifying a domain name and the columns they wish to use to generate the PURL.

So, for example, the user could specify a domain of **stackoverflow.com** and the columns **first name** and **last name**. The resulting PURL would be:

`http://stackoverflow.com/JamesHill`.

The only real challenge with this add-in is ensure the uniqueness of the PURL. Let's say that there are two James Hill's. In that case, the following PURLs should be generated:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/JamesHill
http://stackoverflow.com/JamesHill1
```

**Question**

What would be the best way to ensure the uniqueness of the PURLs, assuming that I have a `List<CustomObject>` each of which contain a PURL property (string). I guess I'm looking for a C# equivalent of SQL's `OVER` and `PARTITION BY`.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Additional Information**

Once the PURLs have been generated in Excel, the data will be returned to our customer for data processing. At some point, the data will be imported into the DB that handles our PURL server requests. The purpose of the add-in is to allow a non-programmer to quickly generate PURLs and return them to the customer without programmer involvement.

Comment: you really should be storing these in a db...

Comment: @DanielA.White, They will be stored in a DB...eventually. Often times the data processing is done outside of the building. A customer will send us their data, ask us to generate PURLs, and then return the data to them. I've been tasked to remove programmers from this process. Basically, once the PURL is generated and returned to the customer, the data will be imported in the DB that handles our PURL server requests.

Comment: What about a simple dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two most common solutions are

**1)** to use a `HashSet<K>` if you want to test only for the uniqueness of the key.

```
var purlsSet = new HashSet<string>();
purlsSet.Add("http://stackoverflow.com/JamesHill");
...
if (purlsSet.Contains("http://stackoverflow.com/JamesHill") {
    ...
}
```

**2)** to use a `Dictionary<K,V>` if you want to store a key as well as the value.

```
var purlsDict = new Dictionary<string, CustomObject>();
CustomObject customObject = ...;
purlsDict.Add("http://stackoverflow.com/JamesHill", customObject);
...

if (purlsDict.ContainsKey("http://stackoverflow.com/JamesHill") {
    ...
}

// OR

if (purlsDict.TryGetValue("http://stackoverflow.com/JamesHill", out customObject) {
    ...
}
```

You could also use a `OrderedDictionary`, which combines the functionality of both, the list and the dictionary, or a `SortedDictionary<K,V>` if you want to have the entries to be always sorted.

Comment: I was hoping for something more elegant like SQL's `OVER` and `PARTITION BY` but this got me started down the right path. Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking for a SQL way of retrieving unique values use `SELECT DISTINCT purl FROM table`. If you are looking for a way of detecting duplicates use `SELECT purl FROM table GROUP BY purl HAVING COUNT(purl) > 1`.

Comment: Not looking for a SQL way, just a C# way that was as elegant as SQL. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use the LINQ extension methods `Distinct` or `GroupBy` in the much the same way.